# pe:triStateCheckbox doesn't work with p:ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm using PF 5.1 + PF Extensions 3.0.0 + OmniFaces 1.8.1 on WAS 8.0.0.10

Trying to make the following example from [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/triStateCheckbox.jsf)
`<pe:triStateCheckbox/>` but listener not called when I change state of a component, neither error is given.

This is my code of **JSF** page:

```
<pe:triStateCheckbox style="vertical-align:middle;" value="#{bean.notification}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.toggleNotification}"/>
</pe:triStateCheckbox>
```

and bean:

```
private int notification;

public void toggleNotification() {
    System.out.println("toggle");
}

//getters and setters
```

What may I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, code in a showcase not same code in a real world. Went to [github](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/views/triStateCheckbox.xhtml) we need to specify the event name:

```
<pe:triStateCheckbox id="ajaxTriState" value="#{triStateCheckBoxController.value2}">
       <p:ajax event="change"
               update="growl"
               listener="#{triStateCheckBoxController.addMessage}"/>
</pe:triStateCheckbox>
```

Comment: please file an issue in the PrimeFaces Extensions github issuelist

Comment: done https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/317